# git svn clone died of signal 11 under cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin, git-svn

I have a problem with `git svn` under `cygwin`

```
user@comp /cygdrive/c/repositories/git/repo $git svn clone --username=username "https://host/svn/repos/repo" .
Initialized empty Git repository in /cygdrive/c/repositories/git/repo/.git/
error: git-svn died of signal 11
```

How to handle this?

```
user@comp ~ $svn --version
svn, version 1.6.15 (r1038135)
   compiled Nov 29 2010, 14:09:28

user@comp ~ $git --version
git version 1.7.4
```

Comment: Had the same thing with centos 4.8. Did you try to use SVN::Client in a simple perl script?

Comment: I have the `git version 1.7.9-rc1` and the `svn version 1.8.5 (r1542147)`.
`perl --version` displays
`This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for cygwin-thread-multi-64int
(with 7 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail).`
And this is the latest versions on the mirror "mirrors.kernel.org".
The next command `perl -e 'require SVN::Core; print "$SVN::Core::VERSION\n"'` executes succesfully.
But `git svn fetch` and `git svn rebase` still shows `error: git-svn died of signal 11`.
What can I try to do else?

Comment: Ok, I've downgraded subversion to `1.7.14` and got an error like `perl unable to remap cygsvn_client-1-0.dll to same address as parent  - try running rebaseall`.
I've exited cygwin, started `ash` and then did `rebaseall` in my working directory (but may be it's possible to run just after `ash` started).
I've started `cygwin` again and `git svn rebase` did all job without errors.
May be new version of svn after `rebaseall` will work too, I haven't time to test it just now.

Answer (score 11):

I found a good tip here:
http://pwizardry.com/devlog/index.cgi/2010/03/29#svn2git

> If you cd to the new repository and type
>   `git svn fetch`
>   it will continue where it left of.

I had the same issue, and the solution seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was figth with this problem for a 5 hours. I was trying to use git from cygwin. But unfortunatly... 
This hucking

```
git-svn died signal 11
```

while trying to do

```
git svn clone http://repo.com/path/to/my/repo.git -s
```

really pissed me of... Addition i doing it after work being on my work place... :) We are used proxy to connect to svn repo from our network.
I was tried rebaseall... Serf internet for solving the problem... But unfortunately unlucky(Не фортануло не повезло...)...

### So i decide that, i hucking, solve this problemm off!

I go to wokr in my holyday and do this:

- Remove git package from my cygwin.
- Remove any another git installation from my windows environment (like tortoisegit)
- Download and install msysgit (http://msysgit.github.io/)
- Install it.
- Configure git to use proxy as below.
- Run cmd.
- execute `git config --global http.proxy http://my.proxy.com:8080`
- Now we need to configure svn to use proxy when you run git svn
  clone. Or else you will get this error:

  ```
  RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/repos/my-project': PROPFIND of '/svn/repos/my-project': could not connect to server (https://my.svn.repository.behinde.proxy.com) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 310
  ```

And this is some tricky. For it we need to edit `/.subversion/servers` in `home` folder. Not  `%appdata%\.subversion\servers` , not `c:\users\userlogin\.subversion\servers` no! You need do next:

- run git bash (that you have after installing msysGit) from

  ```
  "Start" -> all programms -> git -> Git bash.`
  ```

this is a link that point to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i` in my case

- Now you need execute "cd" command.
- Now do

  ```
  ls -al
  ```

  look for `.subversion` folder
- And now edit file under this folder `vi .subversion/servers`
  you need to find section `[groups]` and add your server to what you want to made proxy connection for example:

  ```
  [groups]
      myserver = www.some.server.com
  ```
- Now in same file add strings like this:

  ```
  [myserver]
      http-proxy-host = http[or https]://[login:password_to_proxy@]my.proxy.com
      http-proxy-port = 8080your proxy port
  ```

for example:

```
    [myserver]
        http-proxy-host = http://my.proxy.com
        http-proxy-port = 8080
```

now you are configure all you need (i hope :) )
And now you may run cmd and make `git svn clone https://your.repository.com/path/to/repo -s`

And work with svn using git svn for your pleasure. :)

Comment: Thanks. This saved my day, as in a corporate environment `.subversion\server` are under `%HOMESHARE%`, but in a standalone Windows installation under `%USERPROFILE%`. And `Git bash` knows where to look in which case.

Comment: What? You execute "cd" command to go to your's user home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `perl -e 'require SVN::Core; print "$SVN::Core::VERSION\n"'`.  That should print '1.6.15' in your case.  If it spits out an error instead, it probably means that you don't have the perl SVN module installed.  Try installing the 'subversion-perl' package in cygwin.

Comment: `user@comp $perl -e 'require SVN::Core; print "$SVN::Core::VERSION\n"'
1.6.15`

Comment: perl -e 'require SVN::Core; print "$SVN::Core::VERSION\n"' gives me segmentation fault. But writing the code in .pl file and then executing perl script gives output '1.6.11'. Should be okay I suppose. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to not being able to reach the repository.

I had to add my proxy settings to `~/.subversion/servers` to let svn be able to check it out.

Comment: It is really worth to check the SVN/subversion proxy settings, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `git-svn` crashes with [*Segmentation fault*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (that could indicate a software bug). The `git-svn` executable file is just a plain perl script, so to fix it you've the following possibilities:

- upgrade `perl` and make sure it uses that new version,
- try changing *shebang* of `git-svn` binary into upgraded `perl`,
- re-install `subversion` to use upgraded bindings to perl:

  - OS X: `brew reinstall subversion --with-perl` then`brew link --overwrite subversion`
  - Linux: `apt-get install git-svn libsvn-perl`
- locate other non-crashing `git-svn` and use them instead, e.g.

  ```
  which -a git-svn
  locate git-svn | grep git-svn$
  ```

If you're on OS X, check for more ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28228016/55075).