# git svn clone died of signal 11 on OSX

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to migrate a project from svn to git. I was using the osx svn package, but I also tried installing with homebrew. I keep getting this same error.

```
git svn clone http://myserver/myrepo
error: git-svn died of signal 11
```

Version information:

```
git --version
git version 2.2.1

svn --version
svn, version 1.7.17 (r1591372)
   compiled Sep 18 2014, 13:06:44
```

I'm running Yosemite.

Comment: I would suggest uninstalling these, and just download XCode which has both git and svn in reasonably new versions.

Comment: in case you installed git via brew before upgrading to yosemite you might need to update your git installation via brew (`brew upgrade git`) - there were [yosemite-related fixes in brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/31310)

Comment: What does `git svn --version` say?  You have to do this in a git repository, doesn't matter which one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`git svn` executes `git-svn` which is a Perl program which uses bindings to libsvn and those bindings are touchy.  If Perl changes, or SVN changes, that could cause a segfault.  Both could happen in an OS upgrade.

Find out which version of the SVN bindings your git is using.  Here's what I get for OS X 10.10.1

```
$ /usr/bin/git svn --version
git-svn version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50) (svn 1.7.17)
```

Try `brew upgrade git` as suggested by @MykolaGurov in the comments.  It seems there are [fixes for 10.10 and git-svn](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/31310).  You might also try `brew reinstall subversion --with-perl` to reinstall the Perl bindings.

Or use the OS X provided /usr/bin/git which will be built with the OS provided SVN and Perl.

Or try [MacPorts](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.macports.org%2F), I use it and its git-svn works.  `port install git +svn`.

Comment: reinstalling the Perl bindings after upgrading git worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: `brew upgrade git` and `brew reinstall subversion --perl` worked for me

Comment: After OS X upgrade: If `brew upgrade git` says the newest version is already installed, and you still get `signal 11`, try `brew uninstall git` and then reinstall with `brew install git`.

Comment: From the log when reinstalling subversion: `subversion: --perl was deprecated; using --with-perl instead!`.

Comment: `--perl`/`--with-perl` no longer seem to be valid options.

Answer (score 5):

First thing to do, is to debug `git` command to see on which component it fails by adding `GIT_TRACE=1`, e.g.

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git svn clone https://example.com/svn/foo/ foo
21:12:40.239238 git.c:557               trace: exec: 'git-svn' 'clone' 'https://example.com/svn/foo/ foo/' 'foo'
21:12:40.240158 run-command.c:347       trace: run_command: 'git-svn' 'clone' 'https://example.com/svn/foo/ foo/' 'foo'
error: git-svn died of signal 11
```

and re-run the last command in the corrupted repository which shows that the crash happened in `git-svn` binary.

In order to do that, you need to identify where you've `git-svn` binary, e.g.

```
$ which -a git-svn
$ locate git-svn | grep git-svn$
/Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn
/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/libexec/git-core/git-svn
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn
/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn
/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.4.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.0/libexec/git-core/git-svn
```

If you've multiple `git-svn` binaries, to find out which one is used, run:

```
sudo fs_usage -f exec | grep git
```

in another terminal before running the failing git command again.

Once you've identified which `git-svn` you run, run it directly like:

```
/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn ...
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.0/libexec/git-core/git-svn
```

and it's most likely that it'll crash no matter which parameter you will specify, otherwise specify as shown from trace output.

Sometimes it maybe a symbolic link, so check where it points to, e.g.:

```
$ stat /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn
  File: ‘/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn’ -> ‘/Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn’
```

If that's the case, change the symbolic link to the one which is not crashing, e.g.

```
$ ln -vfs /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn 
‘/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn’ -> ‘/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn’
```

Alternatively identify to which package your `git-svn` belongs to and upgrade accordingly, e.g.

- `/Applications/Xcode.app` -> upgrade Xcode,
- `/Applications/GitHub.app` -> upgrade GitHub app
- `/usr/local/Cellar/git` -> upgrade `git` via Homebrew, e.g.

  ```
  brew upgrade git
  ```

  If Homebrew will complain about the file conflicts, then run:

  ```
  brew link --overwrite git
  ```

If you still crashing after upgrade, use different version (as mentioned above) which doesn't crash, e.g.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn clone https://example.com/svn/foo/ foo
```

If that works for you, add to your `PATH` and later on use `git-svn` command instead, or add an alias, e.g.:

```
alias git-svn='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn'
```

If you got any missing dependencies for the new `git-svn`, install `Git::SVN` by running:

```
sudo cpan install Git::SVN
```

#### Debugging

If above won't help, you may debug it further more. Here are some suggestions to run in separate terminal, then in run the failing command:

```
sudo dtruss -fn git
```

or:

```
sudo dtruss -fn git-svn
```

To identify which `git-svn` is called, you may try:

- `sudo /usr/bin/newproc.d`
- `sudo fs_usage -f exec | grep git`

Answer (score 0):

My case was different. I specified credentials in the https url to my svn repo.
Removing the credentials solved the issue.

How I ran the command

```
git svn https://<key>:<pass>@example.com/repo
```

removed key/pass and the command passes.