# git svn clone fails with "error: git-svn died of signal 11"

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to move my huge SVN repository into Git using a Ubuntu 16.4 machine. For this purpose I am following this tutorial:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/svn-to-git-prepping-your-team-migration

I have installed the latest Git, SVN and git-svn tools.

My problem is that each time I rung the 'git svn clone' command I am getting this error 'error: git-svn died of signal 11' without any further information.

Searching a bit in this forum I found another post:

[git svn clone died of signal 11 under cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282405/git-svn-clone-died-of-signal-11-under-cygwin)

That took me to this web site for a solution:

http://pwizardry.com/devlog/index.cgi/2010/03/29#svn2git

Asking to resume the process using 'git svn fetch'. I did so and it seemed to work as the process went on for one more day. Unfortunately it has stopped again with the same error and the 'git svn fetch' doesn't seem to help any.

I would like to know if someone has experienced this problem or how could I find any traces because all i get is this error without any further explanation.

**EDIT:**

So I continued searching regarding this issue and I found that you could get some more information if using 'valgrind', and so I did, and now the 'git svn fetch' stops in another point with this message:

```
==17006== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()
==17006== 
==17006== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17006==     in use at exit: 43,779,830 bytes in 71,103 blocks
==17006==   total heap usage: 7,178,701 allocs, 7,107,598 frees, 2,123,468,574 bytes allocated
==17006== 
==17006== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17006==    definitely lost: 156,556 bytes in 40 blocks
==17006==    indirectly lost: 156,338 bytes in 51 blocks
==17006==      possibly lost: 43,394,719 bytes in 70,805 blocks
==17006==    still reachable: 72,217 bytes in 207 blocks
==17006==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==17006==                         newarray           : 53,032 bytes in 1,637 blocks
==17006==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17006== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==17006== 
==17006== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17006== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Any idea what is this?

**EDIT 2:**

I see now that running my normal 'git svn fetch' says all is done... I don't see how the use of 'valgrind' affected but it seems that it helped finishing the job.

Comment: Is this about a one-time migration and you will only use Git afterwards, or do you want to commit back to SVN from your Git clone?

Answer (score 15):

This problem is fixed in the `libsvn-perl 1.9.4`.

[libsvn-perl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libsvn-perl&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

[bugs.debian.org](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=780246)

Comment: that version is not available for xenial... besides compilling from the source, is there any other way around?

Comment: just in case somebody has the same issue that I did (very very large repository, ubuntu xenial): just keep doing fetch until it gets all the repo. Don't mind the signal 11. Just keep fetching.

Comment: In xenial you can use a ppa repository to install a newer libsvn-perl, check: https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/ubuntu/subversion-1.9

Comment: @cauchy It works for most of repos, but there was a specific commit in an SVN repo that would create the `signal 11` every time, and so, the migration couldn't advance. The update of the library to the ppa linked by @epineda fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: Hi Vampire. I appreciate your answer. Thank you very much. However, besides the initial problems I had performing the svn clone described in my initial question, the rest looks pretty good to me. The history created keeps all the contents as it was in SVN. The tags are created as branches or tags, whatever you like, see: http://www.sailmaker.co.uk/blog/2013/05/05/migrating-from-svn-to-git-preserving-branches-and-tags-3 For the rest I am not sure, but I would say that playing a bit with the local repository generated it can also be hacked to join or split SVN repositories.

Comment: Git is almost almighty. Of course you can manipulate a repository in any thinkable way including overcoming some of the shortcomings of `git-svn`. If you prefer it that way, be my guest. :-) Just sharing my experiences.

Comment: svn2git is a nice wrapper but it also uses svn-git so the segfault issue stays the same. E.g.:
# svn2git MY_URL_REMOVED
error: git-svn died of signal 11
command failed:
git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk='trunk' --tags='tags' --branches='branches' MY_URL_REMOVED

Comment: Please re-read my answer. The `svn2git` you are talking about is not the one I talk about as I also explain in my answer. The one I talk about is a completely different and separate tool that does not depend on `git-svn`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after i upgraded to **macOS BigSur version 11.0.1** from **Catalina**. I use brew and ran `brew upgrade` after my OS upgrade. `brew upgrade` installed latest version of PERL and symbolic linked `/usr/local/bin/perl` along with upgrading git to 2.29.2. The following steps fixed my issue

1. Check perl path in the terminal using `which perl`
2. Check which perl `git-svn` script at `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.29.2/libexec/git-core/git-svn` is pointing to (on the first line) and update if its not the same as the one from step 1

In my case `which perl` was spitting out `/usr/local/bin/per` however the perl in `git-svn` scipt was pointing to `/usr/bin/perl`. Changing this path to `/usr/local/bin/per` and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upgrade git even subversion but the error still exists. so I have my Ubuntu upgrade to `18.04` from 16.04 the error gone. now the **git svn --version** output's:

```
git-svn version 2.19.2 (svn 1.9.7)
```

still on the road to get used to 18.04, so don't upgrade if you worry about that.