# Svn to git migration handling big repositories

Tags: git, svn, migration, svn2git

I'm working on migration svn repository to git (gerrit) and I'm encountering issues regarding migrating big repository. I use svn2git.

> fatal: malformed index info 10 
>   error: git-svn died of signal 11 
>   xxxxxx@svn2git-import:~$ Connection reset by XX.XXX.XX.XX

I added --log-window-sized in svn2git which is set to 100000.

Thank you for advance help!

Comment: This seems to be a similar problem to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534064/git-svn-clone-fails-with-error-git-svn-died-of-signal-11), which has some useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding another 0 in log window size. Silly me.

Just edit the svn2git -> /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/svn2git-2.4.0/lib/svn2git/migration.rb

add

> --log--window-size 9999999999999

in

> git svn fetch

solved my problem!

Answer (score -3):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of a repository. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

The `svn2git` tool you used (probably nirvdrums) is based on `git-svn` and as such suffers from most of the same drawbacks, just working around some few of them.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories like yours that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly in one run if you like.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` or the nirvdrum `svn2git` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)